# How to filter items from array of objects based on another array of strings using javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

i want to filter the array of objects based on array of strings using javascript.

i have input array of object like so,

```
const input = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'first',
        type: 'first_type',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'second',
        type: 'second_type',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'third',
        type: 'third_type',
    },
]; 


const chosen_items = ['1','2']
```

now i want to filter the items in input whose id match with chosen_items. so the expected output is like below,

```
const output = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'first',
        type: 'first_type',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'second',
        type: 'second_type',
    },
]
```

i have tried like below but that gives wrong output. its maybe filtering the input based on index.

```
const output = React.useMemo(
  () => chosen_items.map(id => input[id]).filter(negate(isNil)),
  [input, chosen_items]
);
```

with above code snippet i get output like below,

```
output = [
    {
         id: 2,
         name: 'second',
         type: 'second_type',
     },
     {
         id: 3,
         name: 'third',
         type: 'third_type',
     },
 ]
```

could someone help me fix this. how to filter input based on its id. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter()` to do it,pay attention that in `input`,id is number,while in the `chosen_items` id is character.

```js
const input = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'first',
        type: 'first_type',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'second',
        type: 'second_type',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'third',
        type: 'third_type',
    },
]; 


const chosen_items = ['1','2']

let result = input.filter(a => chosen_items.includes(a.id + ''))
console.log(result)
```