# Filter JSON objects based on array variable with multiple attributes in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

**Context**
I am using: Windows 11, VSCode and node v18.12.1

I am trying to filter a JSON object, using an array variable, as I have more than one value I want to filter against.

**Question**
I have the following code working which filters based on a single user's name. What I want to do is filter based on matching one or more of the names.

**Here is the code that's working filtering on one owner's name**

```
let carOwners = [{ "name": "Phil", "age": 52, "car": null },
{ "name": "Carl Phil", "age": 25, "car": "Tesla" },
{ "name": "Bob", "age": 65, "car": "Land Rover" },
{ "name": "Megan", "age": 34, "car": "Mercedez" },
{ "name": "Charlene", "age": 67, "car": "Mazda" }]

checkUsers = carOwners.filter(user => !(user.name.includes("Phil")));

console.log(checkUsers);
```

which gives the result:

```
[
  { name: 'Bob', age: 65, car: 'Land Rover' },
  { name: 'Megan', age: 34, car: 'Mercedez' },
  { name: 'Charlene', age: 67, car: 'Mazda' }
]
```

What I want to do is filter out any results that contain Phil or Bob.

**What I've tried**
I have searched various other solutions, but they don't seem to cater for what I'm after...

This is the first method tried:

```
filteredNames = ['Phil', 'Bob'];

checkUsers = carOwners.filter(user => !(user.name.includes(filteredNames)));

console.log(checkUsers);
```

The result I'm after is:

```
[
  { name: 'Megan', age: 34, car: 'Mercedez' },
  { name: 'Charlene', age: 67, car: 'Mazda' }
]
```

except I get:

```
[
  { name: 'Phil', age: 52, car: null },
  { name: 'Carl Phil', age: 25, car: 'Tesla' },
  { name: 'Bob', age: 65, car: 'Land Rover' },
  { name: 'Megan', age: 34, car: 'Mercedez' },
  { name: 'Charlene', age: 67, car: 'Mazda' }
]
```

I tried numerous others, the closest I got was based on the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74150538/20331138) I tried the following:

```
const filteredNames = ['Phil', 'Bob'];

let checkUsers = carOwners.filter(a => !(filteredNames.includes(a.name + '')));

console.log(checkUsers);
```

which is closer (as it's filtered out objects with the names Bob and Phil), however I am still returned the object 'Carl Phil', as you can see below... The question I specifically have is how do I filter out any object that contains any appearance of any of the names in the filteredNames array, so that I am left with the objects with the name 'Megan' and 'Charlene'?

```
[
  { name: 'Carl Phil', age: 25, car: 'Tesla' },
  { name: 'Megan', age: 34, car: 'Mercedez' },
  { name: 'Charlene', age: 67, car: 'Mazda' }
]
```

Any advice appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: `console.log(carOwners.filter(f => filteredNames.every(e => !f.name.includes(e))));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have to `filter` an occurrence of the given names anywhere in the string, a good catch is to use regular expressions. In this case, we're looking for `name`s that do not `match` `some` of the `filteredNames`.

You can use a combination of [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to do so.

```js
let carOwners = [{ "name": "Phil", "age": 52, "car": null },
{ "name": "Carl Phil", "age": 25, "car": "Tesla" },
{ "name": "Bob", "age": 65, "car": "Land Rover" },
{ "name": "Megan", "age": 34, "car": "Mercedez" },
{ "name": "Charlene", "age": 67, "car": "Mazda" }]

let filteredNames = ['Phil','Bob']

let newObj = carOwners.filter(({name}) =>
    !filteredNames.some(filtered => name.match(filtered)))

console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

The smarter solution is to use **regular expression** as [testing_22](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12096922/testing-22) posted.
The following codes are not cool but more understandable for people who don't like **regular expression** :)

```
const carOwners = [
  { "name": "Phil", "age": 52, "car": null },
  { "name": "Carl Phil", "age": 25, "car": "Tesla" },
  { "name": "Bob", "age": 65, "car": "Land Rover" },
  { "name": "Megan", "age": 34, "car": "Mercedez" },
  { "name": "Charlene", "age": 67, "car": "Mazda" }
];

const filteredNames = ['Phil', 'Bob'];

const checkUsers = carOwners.filter(({name}) => {
  for (const [index, eachName] of filteredNames.entries()) {
    if (name.includes(eachName)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
});

console.log(checkUsers);
```

Comment: Thanks, @shin! Thanks for providing your alternative, but as you said I was after a succinct expression which @testing_22 solution gives :)

Comment: I'm happy that your problem is solved with regex solution.  
Hope your app goes well :)